# lineSpacingMultiplier causes button text to not center

Tags: android, android-layout

On devices running API 19 I've noticed that the attribute `lineSpacingMultiplier` causes text to not be vertically centered inside Buttons. It seems to be applying the spacing multiplier even though there is only one line of text.

My app theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/trade_gothic_ltstd</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.3</item>
</style>
```

What I get. Note that this button has no padding whatsoever, and removing the `lineSpacingMultipler` from `styles.xml` causes it to be properly centered.

[image: Incorrectly centered button]

Any idea how to fix this? I haven't confirmed exactly which Android version this starts working properly, but it's not an issue on API 26 and above from what I've seen.

Comment: Curious if setting the `android:singleLine="true"` attribute would fix it for this particular instance.

Comment: @kcoppock That was a good idea, but I tried it (and android:lines="1") and it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line Multiplier on API 19 by default adds the space even when there are not more than 1 line. That is an issue present in API 19.

Comment: This is NOT the issue, and it's not even a TextView I'm asking about.

Comment: Yes on API 19 it has this behavior by default.

Comment: @MarkHerscher Button extends TextView.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you have mentioned that its a Button.

Comment: @VishalArora no worries. I just tried it and it did not fix the issue. I confirmed the gravity is being respected by setting it to center_vertical, and the resulting text was left-aligned but still improperly centered vertically in the same way.

Comment: Yes that is true. Line Multiplier on api 19 by default adds the space even when there are not more than 1 line. That is an issue present in 19.

Comment: Well, shoot. I suspected that was the case but I was hoping there was a workaround. Do you have any links to others reporting this issue? I wasn't able to find much by Googling.

Comment: Actually I had the same issue working on one of my projects. So I looked at the TextView's code for API 19 and found this behavior.

Comment: If you want to compare the implementation difference, you can look at the source code for TextView for Api 19 and above.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help. I can't really accept your answer as that didn't fix it, but if you want to post an answer regarding this bug I'll accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187441/discussion-between-vishal-arora-and-mark-herscher).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to verify that this will do the trick, but I believe you could work around this for now with a subclass of `TextView` that caches the desired line spacing multiplier, but only applies it selectively based on the number of lines in the actual layout once the layout pass is complete.

```
public final class LineSpacingTextView extends AppCompatTextView {
    public LineSpacingTextView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public LineSpacingTextView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

        Layout layout = getLayout();
        if (layout != null) {
            adjustLineSpacing(layout);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
        // Cache the last specified line spacing as we may overwrite it
        // when the view is laid out.
        desiredLineSpacingMultiplier = mult;
        Layout layout = getLayout();
        if (layout != null) {
            adjustLineSpacing(layout);
        } else {
            super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
        }
    }

    private float adjustLineSpacing(@NonNull Layout layout) {
        // Force line spacing to 1 if the layout has only one line.
        float adjustedLineSpacingMultiplier = 
                layout.getLineCount() == 1
                ? 1f
                : desiredLineSpacingMultiplier;

        // Only set if changed, as this may be called recursively from
        // setLineSpacing otherwise.
        if (getLineSpacingMultiplier() != adjustedLineSpacingMultiplier) {
            super.setLineSpacing(getLineSpacingExtra(), adjustedLineSpacingMultiplier);
        }
    }
}
```